# Display 3 divs based on sql db

Tags: php, html, sql

Im trying to display 3 divs with content but i get errors, im kind new with php and sql.
i think there is an error on line 22 but i dont know how to fix it

```
<?
$con=mysqli_connect("host","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
$resultado = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM diario ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
?> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Titulo</title>
<style>
.cajas{
width: 160px;
height: 250px;
border: 1px grey solid;
box-shadow: 6px 6px 7px 5px #CCCCCC;
float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

 echo <div class="cajas"><p>$row['tit'];</p></div>
 }
?> 
</body>
</html>
<?
 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: should be `echo '<div class="cajas"><p>'.$row['tit'].'</p></div>';`

Answer (score 0):

solution 1: use strings, as  are not elements of the php language

```
echo "<div class='cajas'><p>".$row['tit']."</p></div>"
```

solution 2: seperate php from html

```
<?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
      ?>
          <div class="cajas"><p>
              <?php
                  echo $row['tit'];
              ?>
          </p></div>
      <?php
    }
?>
```

I prefer solution 1, as I try to stay close to php, but others prefer the second way as it stays closer to html (and more IDE's provide html syntax coloring)

Answer (score 0):

the php tag must be like this

```
<?php (your code here) ?>
```

this is for fetching

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo "<div class='cajas'><p>$row[tit]</p></div>";
    }
?>
```